Bi-Quartz Polarimeter
I have confusion regarding bi-quartz polarimeter, that when we try to measure specific rotation of a compound with respect to another compound (like water), when do we have to stop for taking readings? Is where the tint of passage appears then we have to stop?
If yes, please explain what is of tint of passage, and why do we have to take readings only on tint of passage?
Another doubt is that, for example, specific rotation of cane sugar (Sucrose) is 66.5 degrees for sodium D-line light.
So, my question is that in Bi-Quartz polarimeter, we use white light (mercury lamp) as a source of light and then how do we know that we are calculating specific rotation for sodium D line light only and not for any other wavelength? Also, can we calculate specific rotation for different wavelengths of a given compound in the Bi-Quartz polarimeter?

To find the angle of rotation of the polarization, you have to measure the angle  you have to turn the device to reach the tint of passage. The tint of passage appears when the polarization of the light is aligned with the separation of your quartz plate. The quartz plate is designed such that a specific color is extinguished in such configuration (often the yellow because of the sensitivity of the eye).
You surely know that the angle of rotation is a function of $\lambda$, so for a polychromatic source, you'll have different angle of rotation for different $\lambda$. Let's say your source is composed of two spectral lines at $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. To these two wavelengths are associated two different angles of rotations $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

Can tint of passage be violet in colour and how do i know the tint of passage is which colour for my bi quartz polarimeter and also i never heard that tint of passage  is yellow(why?). @MauvaiseFoi

The tint isn't yellow, it's often red/violet ("lie de vin" in French). The yellow is the color you extinguish. You can make a tint of a different color if you use a thicker or thiner quartz plate I think

oh ,so any recommendation where i can study bi quartz polarimeter with good explaination with deep concepts. And also one more question then when we take reading at tint of passage when yellow colour is extinguished. Does it mean that  at that colour or wavelength which is extinguished we are taking specific rotation reading for that extinguished wavelength. @MauvaiseFoi

I have some resources in French, but found this one file (at the end )https://www.lkouniv.ac.in/site/writereaddata/siteContent/202004032250571287punit_phy_Polarimetry.pdf

also plz answer the question in above statement also which was written before. @MauvaiseFoi

I'm not sure I've understood your question. But this reading at the tint of passage without optical active medium can be defined as your 0° value. First, you insert water or any other reference without polarimetric effect to calibrate your polarizer/analyzer to observe the tint of passage on a screen. Then, you insert your optical active medium and turn your analyzer to observe again the same tint of passage.
